# Determine Xamarin.Forms iOS App Memory Consumption at Runtime

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I would be like to measure the memory footprint of my **Xamarin.Forms iOS App** at runtime, preferably via code and not some tool. 
To give you some background information, I need to track down some memory leaks within my App. I am aware that there are tools like the Xamarin Profiler and XCode's Instruments which should help with this but I found both tools rather useless. Instruments freezes my Apps UI and the Profiler does not provide any delta measurements
 The memory measurement I am looking for should be as close as possible to what iOS considers the App's footprint. I read a couple of posts and some people claim the way to go would be using

```
    long byteNumber = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
```

I tried this approach and got some memory value of 65 MB right before iOS terminated my App since it hit 1400 MB memory consumption! Clearly, the value reported by the garbage collector is only a small part of what is going on. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Xamarin DOESN'T know how much memory native objects hold, so that's why you get this result...